# Magento2 add custom jquery plugin

Tags: magento2, jquery

How can I add [this JQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/perfect-scrollbar/) into Magento 2 store?

Comment: which pages you want to put the library?

Comment: @St3phan, i need to change scrollbar on every page

Comment: Check this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html)